# Logql query avg and sum gives same result

Tags: logging, grafana-loki, logql

I have a logql query for loki on nginx like this:

```
sum(avg_over_time({$label_name=~"$label_value", job=~"$job", instance=~"$instance"} | json | status=200 | unwrap status | __error__="" [$__interval])) by (upstream)
```

this gives me the result same as

```
avg(avg_over_time({$label_name=~"$label_value", job=~"$job", instance=~"$instance"} | json | status=200 | unwrap status | __error__="" [$__interval])) by (upstream)
```

It means `sum` and `avg` result are the same and both gives me the sum of values.
What is wrong with my query?

Comment: I could not reproduce the issue (I mean, "sum" and "avg" produced different results to me). Have you verified what is the "avg_over_time(...)" function (without the "sum" and the "avg") result?

Comment: It was grafana settings in calculation, it was set on Total. changed it to Mean and the problem solved!